# Does Allah love those who don't love him?

Tags: quran, tafseer, allah

In the same way a man can have genuine and deep platonic love for another man that is either indifferent to him or even dislikes him.

Comment: Allah's رحمة (compassion \ mercy) extends to everyone, ورحمتي وسعت كل شيء 
 [7:156](https://quran.com/7/156) **"** *My mercy encompasses all things* **"**. As for His محبة (love) it does not extend to everyone regardless of their actions.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your notion that someone (I am speaking of humans) can have a deep platonic love for someone who dislikes him. Maybe we can want the best for someone, but "deep platonic love" is a bit too far.

Answer (score -1):

Praise be to God

Firstly:

God loves all of His creatures and for that reason He sent prophets and messengers to teach us the truth and guide us to the straight path. God and the believers want people to choose the way of righteousness and thereby enter Paradise, but God does not love sinful actions. A person who rejects God, commits evil deeds, and dies without repentance will be denied the blessings of God’s love. Therefore, we should become familiar with the characteristics of those whom God loves and does not love as mentioned in the Quran because God Says:

> “Say, ‘If you love God, then follow me; God will love you and forgive you your sins, and God is all-forgiving, all-merciful.”
>
> ”Verily, God loves those who rely upon Him. “**(Surah Ali Imran 3:159)**
>
> ”Verily, Allah loves the Godfearing.” **(Surah Ali Imran 3:76)**
>
> ”Behave well. Verily, God loves those who are good.” **(Surah Al-Baqarah 2:195)**

God does not love stubborn rejection of faith, committing sins, and showing ingratitude.

God Says:

> ”Verily, God does not love the unbelievers.” **(Surah Ali Imran 3:32)**
>
> ”Verily, God does not love the transgressors.” **(Surah Al-Baqarah 2:190)**

And if someone does not love Him why should He love him? Does it make sense? I mean if you are a transgressor, then He might not love you even though you believe in Him, but if you disbelieve in Him and do more bad than good, then He will not love you and He will Punish you for doing evil and changing the true belief.

**CONCLUSION:** God does not love those who do not love Him, because those who don’t love Him are the oppressors, transgressors and those who commit shirk and disbelief and die in state of disbelief, including the stubborn disbelievers. He loves only those who truly love Him because they do good, fear Him, pray to Him and they stay away from sinful things as much as possible and they always repent to Him. Of course He can, but He preferred and choosed to like only those who truly love Him.

I hope I gave you good answer.

And God knows best

Comment: The question is about Allah loving (or not loving) those who do not love Him. It is not about Allah not loving evil people or disbelievers. If your intention is to link those who do not love Allah to disbelievers, you need to do so in your answer.

Comment: @III-AK-III Well In here I referred that, if this person does not love Him then why should He love him?

Comment: @III-AK-III How about now?